# Message: System.Exception : iOS tests are not supported on Windows?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, specflow

Hi I have a quesions related to this problem 
someone could solve it ?

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow is not a free coding, coding tutorial or even a tech support website. Please read all of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Xamarin.UITests in iOS is not suppored so far using windows with mac agent. You would need to run VS for Mac for that.

More information [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71138/how-to-run-test-using-vs-on-ios-simulator-on-mac#latest)

Comment: @ccalvi No workaround and solution so far, see the doc: [working-with-ios-simulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-ios-simulator?tabs=vswin)